# Finding phase of voltage divider

Tags: voltage, voltage-divider

I have this AC voltage divider here wish I want to find the exit voltage of. What I've done is I've applied the voltage divider formula:

$$ V_{out} = \frac{Z_2}{Z_1 + Z_2} V_{in}$$

Now that I have got the magnitude of \$ V_{out} \$, I am trying to figure out the sinusoidal function associated with it. But I'm not exactly sure how to do it

Diagram of this scenario:

[image]

$$ Z_{R-L} = \sqrt{ R^2 + w^2 L^2}$$

$$ Z_{C} = \frac{1}{wC}$$

hence,

$$ V_{out} = \frac{ V_{in}}{ 1+ wC \sqrt{R^2 + w^2 L^2} } $$

assume \$V_{in}\$ to be some generic sinusoidal function like \$ V_{in} = A sin( \omega t)\$

Comment: Can you show us your complex expression for the voltage divider?

Comment: How do you mean ? you mean with the values?

Comment: With L,R,C  and preferably simplified into real and imaginary components.

Comment: pl check the edit that I have made ( I am new to electronic so sorry if mistake)

Comment: To get the phase you're going to have to invite Mr. "j" to the party (j = \$\sqrt{-1}\$).

Comment: why don't you call him 'i' ? :thinking:

Comment: Electrical engineers usually use j rather than i, because we prefer to reserve i for current.

Comment: I think capital I is used more often than i .

Comment: @HelenaWells I is used for DC current and i(t) for varying or i for small-signal current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question's values for impedances \$Z_{R-L}\$ and \$Z_C\$ are actually the magnitude of those impedances.  I suspect that the approach was mixing time-domain and frequency-domain approaches; I will address both to make the distinction.

Since the inductor voltage depends on changing current and the capacitor current depends on changing voltage, a time domain analysis produces a differential equation.

$$ v_{OUT}(t) = v_C(t) = v_{IN}(t) - L\frac{d}{dt}i_{IN}(t) - Ri_{IN}(t) $$

and since the input current is split between the capacitor and output:
$$   i_{IN}(t) = C\frac{d}{dt}v_{OUT}(t) + i_{OUT}(t)     $$
putting them together:
$$ \begin{align} v_{OUT}(t) &= v_{IN}(t) - L\frac{d}{dt}\big(C\frac{d}{dt}v_{OUT}(t) + i_{OUT}(t)\big) - R\big(C\frac{d}{dt}v_{OUT}(t) + i_{OUT}(t)\big)  \\
                            &= v_{IN}(t) - LC\frac{d^2}{dt^2}v_{OUT}(t) - L\frac{d}{dt}i_{OUT}(t) - RC\frac{d}{dt}v_{OUT}(t) - Ri_{OUT}(t) \\
\end{align}$$

This is still somewhat manageable, except that \$i_{OUT}\$ likely also depends on \$v_{OUT}\$.  Flipping to the frequency domain, the diff-eq turns to algebra and we get a much better handle on the output load.

Let's show the output load explicitly, with an impedance of \$Z_{LOAD}\$.  Also note that L and C have impedances \$j\omega L\$ and \$\frac{1}{j\omega C}\$, respectively.  See [this concise reference](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/impcom.html) for more detail there.
$$ $$
[image: schematic]

Preserving our output nets, we can lump together L with R (in series) and C with the load (parallel).  This gives:

$$ \begin{align} Z_{LR} &= j\omega L + R \\
Z_{COUT} &= \bigg({\frac{1}{j\omega C}}^{-1}+{Z_{LOAD}}^{-1}\bigg)^{-1} \\
         &= \frac{Z_{LOAD}}{j\omega C Z_{LOAD}+1} \end{align}$$

*Now* you can use the resistor divider rule to calculate a transfer function:
$$ H = \frac{V_{OUT}}{V_{IN}} = \frac{Z_{COUT}}{Z_{LR}+Z_{COUT}} $$

And finally, the phase shift can be determined by comparing the real and imaginary parts of the transfer function:
$$ \Theta = tan^{-1}\biggl(\frac{\mathfrak{Im}(H)}{\mathfrak{Re}(H)}\biggr)$$

Comment: Can you explain what is time and frequency domain? And shuldn't it be arctangent at the end?

Comment: Oh, you are right!  I will fix that right away and will try find a good reference for time/frequency domains.

Comment: I think a good way to understand time domain and frequency domain may be to look at the [Fourier Transform](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Introduction) from one to the other.

Comment: some people say fourier and some tell me laplace... what is difference?

Comment: I still don't understand time vs frequency domain..

Comment: Laplace is more abstract, but accomplishes the same type of transform.  Fourier is a better starting point.  I'm tempted to add time/freq overview to my answer, but I think it makes more sense as a separate question.

Comment: I can't find any good answers on this site about... pls help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110764/discussion-between-mbedded-and-ddd4c4u).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to know real values and want to examine different scenarios then use an [on-line calculator](http://www.stades.co.uk/RLC%20filters/RLC%20LPF.html) to give the frequency response of this: -

[image]

Here's an example: -

[image]

You also get the formulas and derivation: -

[image]

Comment: 1. What is a filter
2. why did you define 1/Q  = 2 epislon thing? 

( i dont knwo what symbol is called)

Comment: The RLC circuit is a filter. It's a low pass filter, 2nd order type. the squiggly line is zeta, damping factor. Q is filter quality factor.

Comment: can you explain these things in more detail? I haven't heard of these terms before like filter, damping factor. I've heard Q but , only basic understanding I have of it

Comment: I think you might be out of your depth here. There is a whole term of coursework implied to understand this.

Answer (score -1):

You cant just add voltages in AC because the voltage drop of the resistor is in a different phase with the voltage drop of the capacitor and is in a different phase with the voltage drop of the inductor.

In AC generally:

Current through a resistor has the same phase with the voltage drop of the resistor.

In capacitors current leads voltage by pi/2 rad.

In inductors voltage leads current by pi/2 rad.

To find the total voltage drop you must draw this diagram:

[image]

The total voltage drop across all circuit elements will be sqrt(Vr^2+Vl^2+Vc^2).

To get the output voltage hide all the lines which represent the voltage drop of the resistor and the inductor:

Since we only have circuit elements connected in series the voltage will steal lead the current so the graph will look like that:

[image]

where I = Current.

I am a stubborn woman!

Comment: well problem is the circuit is branching out from the capacitor

Comment: so, I don't think I can really add it like that

Comment: Just made a random circuit to show the OP how it is done.

Comment: I'm op, and  I'd like advice more in context with this problem / how to fix my approach

Comment: I don't think everything is in series

Comment: coz like near the capacitor there are two nodes which are branching out

Comment: Yes but the 2 branches are not connected to anywhere so  we can ignore it.

Comment: It's connected to some other element, like their's a load ( I think)

Comment: Phase shift is not \$\pi/4\$, but rather \$\pi/2\$.

Comment: Oups yes you are correct I always had trouble converting degrees to radians.

Comment: From the image you give me I don't see any load update your image.